# Iterate over keyless array with mustache?

Tags: javascript, mustache

I have an array that looks like this:

```
[
    Object
        actions: Array[2]
        comments: Object
        created_time: "2012-06-14T17:45:34+0000"
        from: Object
        id: "2388163605_10150972634368606"
        message: "På jakt efter lift Visby/oskarshamn- Malmö efter almedalsveckan antingen söndagen den 8 juli eller morgon/fm den 9 Juli... Bensinpengar och choklad utlovas... spännande historier kan berättas på begäran."
        to: Object
        type: "status"
        updated_time: "2012-06-14T21:45:15+0000"
        __proto__: Object
    , 
    Object
        actions: Array[2]
        comments: Object
        created_time: "2012-06-14T17:45:34+0000"
        from: Object
        id: "2388163605_10150972634368606"
        message: "På jakt efter lift Visby/oskarshamn- Malmö efter almedalsveckan antingen söndagen den 8 juli eller morgon/fm den 9 Juli... Bensinpengar och choklad utlovas... spännande historier kan berättas på begäran."
        to: Object
        type: "status"
        updated_time: "2012-06-14T21:45:15+0000"
        __proto__: Object
    , 
    Object
        actions: Array[2]
        comments: Object
        created_time: "2012-06-13T11:30:35+0000"
        from: Object
        id: "2388163605_10150969775613606"
        message: "Har en båtbiljett Nynäshamn-Visby avg 11.05 nu på fredag!"
        to: Object
        type: "status"
        updated_time: "2012-06-13T11:30:35+0000"
        __proto__: Object
    , 
    Object
        actions: Array[2]
        comments: Object
        created_time: "2012-05-21T10:36:18+0000"
        from: Object
        id: "103138046395999_394844430558691"
        message: "Hej, är det någon som pendlar Visby-Sthlm-Visby? Jag skulle behöva ha hjälp att få hem en byrå från Sthlm. Den är monterad så den där ganska stor. Så behövs släp,lastbil eller större personbil. Mvh Sabina "
        to: Object
        type: "status"
        updated_time: "2012-05-21T10:36:18+0000"
        __proto__: Object
]
```

I try to itterate and print out every message using mustache. This is the template i try to use:

```
<ul>
    {{#.}}
         <li>{{message}}</li>
    {{/.}}
</ul>
```

This is how I post the array into the template:

```
var template = $('#trips').html();
var content = locationIndex[loc.title];
var html = Mustache.to_html(template, content);
$('#right').html(html);
```

the template is defined like this:

```
<script id="trips" type="text/template">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <ul>
            {{#.}}
            <li>{{message}}</li>
            {{/.}}
        </ul>
    </div>
</script>
```

This is a method I've used before, and it seems to work now aswell...

The template works, because the Ul-tag is rendered, but I don't seem to reference the array properly. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That array notation is unfamiliar to me. What kind of syntax is that? Some kind of console log?

Comment: How are you passing the array value into the (compiled) template? Post the corresponding JavaScript statement.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas, yes. Is there a way to print out the actual object?

Comment: I updated the code with more details and also an exact copy of the array from google chrome console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

Template:

```
<script id="trips" type="text/template">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <ul>
            {{#array}}
            <li>{{message}}</li>
            {{/array}}
        </ul>
    </div>
</script>
```

JavaScript:

```
var html = Mustache.to_html( template, { array: content } );
```

I'm assuming that the `content` variable contains an array.

Answer (score 0):

see my response here 
[Mustache JS Template with JSON Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11819006/mustache-js-template-with-json-collection/18576523#18576523)

**data = { 'roles': data }**

The below is the json call via web api

```
      $.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url: '/api/TestApi/GetAllRole',
    success: function (data) {          
        `
```

**data = { 'roles': data };**

```
 // formatting the data to support the mustache    format  
        var html = Mustache.to_html($('#RoleTemplate').html(), data);
        $('#tblRole').append(html);

    }
})
```