# Mustache.js: Iterate over a list received via json

Tags: mustache

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mustache JS Template with JSON Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11819006/mustache-js-template-with-json-collection)

I have a json response like this that I want to use with Mustache.js:

```
[
    {"id": "1", "details": {"name": "X", "type":"Y" }},
    {"id": "2", "details": {"name": "aName", "type":"something" }}
]
```

How do I iterate over this using mustache.js?

Comment: I don't see how it is a duplicate. Neither the linked question's title is descriptive, nor there is an accepted answer.

Comment: The funny thing is, the post that this is "a duplicate of" references this question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found another way of doing this which is pretty similar to Geert-Jan except that you do not have to assign the array to a Javascript object.

```
{{ #. }}
   <p> {{ id }} </p>
   <ul> {{#details}}
        {{name }}
        {{ type }}
   {{/details}}
   </ul>
{{ /. }}
```

Comment: yep indeed. Didn't know the dot worked on a top-level object as well.

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work using I Can Haz. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work (I'm using I Can Haz). Is there something I'm missing, because this would be awesome!

Comment: the first {{/.}} needs to be {{#.}}

Comment: I am not able to make it work, any other iterators you guys suggest

Comment: I have appended the incoming json data like data = { 'roles': data };
$.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: '/api/TestApi/GetAllRole',
        success: function (data) {          
            data = { 'roles': data }; // formatting the data to support the mustache    format  
            var html = Mustache.to_html($('#RoleTemplate').html(), data);
            $('#tblRole').append(html);

        }
    });

Answer (score 16):

The array itself should be a value in a bigger Object, like so:

```
var obj = {
  arr: [
    {"id": "1", "details": {"name": "X", "type":"Y" }},
    {"id": "2", "details": {"name": "aName", "type":"something" }}
  ]
}
```

Then you can do:

```
{{#arr}}
   my id: {{id}}
{{/arr}}
```

the use for {{#bla}} is actually overloaded. When the property it acts upon is an array it will loop. When the property is an object itself it will 'enter' that object. Given your example:

```
{{#arr}}
   my id: {{id}} <br/>
   {{#details}}
     and my name: {{name}}
   {{/details}}
{{/arr}}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I also found another way of doing it which you may find easier as well. Please see below.

Comment: @Geert-Jan thanks it helped me.
I had to do this: `$('.some #selector').append(Mustache.render(someTemplateTpl, {arrayOfObjects: classObject.arrayOfJsons}));`

so array of objects named _arrayOfJsons_ inside class _classObject_ had to be assigned as a value of _arrayOfObjects_ property inside object.
But earlier, when I used this code: `$('.some #selector').append(Mustache.render(someTemplateTpl, classObject.arrayOfJsons));`

it didn't worked, template has been rendered partially - only static html parts, but dynamic ones based on Json's properties (i.e. if-else like statements) weren't. Why?